# Microsoft Overloading the << Operator Sample throws link errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading

I'm trying to compile the Microsoft Sample "[Overloading the << Operator for Your Own Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)" but get the following link error:

> error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
>
> error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class Date const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVDate@@@Z) already defined in Date.obj

Anybody any idea why this is not compiling?

Comment: Do you have a link to the source code?

Comment: Could you post the code that causes this?

Comment: There is nothing that may generate this error message. Sample is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx. It compiles and runs.

Comment: Have you two `.cpp` files: a `main.cpp` and `Date.cpp`? The linker mentions `Date.obj`, but the example consists of a single source file. If you have made any changes can you post them?

Comment: The Microsoft sample didn't suggest a file named "Date.cpp".  Watch out for code in header files.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the definition of the operator inside a header file, you have to declare it `inline`, otherwise it will be defined in all translation units that include that header.

But it's probably better to move it to a implementation file, unless you have strong reasons for having it in a header.

Comment: I managed to get it to run eventually by disabling the use of pre-compiled headers and removing all not needed files including resource files. I think it's related to a VS2008/Windows7 bug issue  but I'm not sure.

Comment: But isn't that what #pragma once is for?  Why doesn't that prevent the linker error?  Your suggesting worked for me, but I'm not sure why the header definition doesn't work even with guards or the pragma.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was was related to multiple definitions and i solved it following a recommendation from Microsoft. In project properties=>Linker=>Command Line=> Additional Options text box add a command "/FORCE:MULTIPLE". This solved my problem. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx)